# Query Slow in Linq, Fast in LinqPad, SQL Management Studio and SQL Profiler

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have this linq query i'm using and it's taking 50 seconds to run when i am running it my asp.net application, however the same query executes in 500ms in LinqPad and Sql Management Studio.

I even took the query from the SQL Profiler and ran it again in SQL Management Studio and it takes around 500ms. What overhead Linq could be doing, that an extra 49s??

Below is the code for reference, thanks for your help.

```
var rCampaign =
    (from a in db.AdCreative
     join h in db.AdHit on a.ID equals h.AdID into gh
     join l in db.AdGroup_Location on a.AdGroupID equals l.AdGroupID into gj
     from subloc in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
     from subhits in gh.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where a.AdGroup.AdHost.Select(q => q.ID).Contains(rPlatform.ID) &&
           a.AdGroup.AdPublisher.Select(q => q.ID).Contains(rPublisher.ID) &&
           a.AdDimensionID == AdSize &&
           a.AdGroup.Campaign.Starts <= rNow &&
           a.AdGroup.Campaign.Ends >= rNow &&
           subhits.HitType == 1 &&
           (subloc == null || subloc.LocationID == rLocationID)
     select new {
         ID = a.ID,
         Name = a.Name,
         Spent = (subhits.AdDimension != null) ? ((double)subhits.AdDimension.Credit / 1000) : 0,
         CampaignID = a.AdGroup.Campaign.ID,
         CampaignName = a.AdGroup.Campaign.Name,
         CampaignBudget = a.AdGroup.Campaign.DailyBudget
     }).GroupBy(adgroup => adgroup.ID)
       .Select(adgroup => new {
           ID = adgroup.Key,
           Name = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().Name,
           Spent = adgroup.Sum(q => q.Spent),
           CampaignID = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignID,
           CampaignName = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignName,
           CampaignBudget = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignBudget,
       })
      .GroupBy(q => q.CampaignID)
      .Select(campaigngroup => new {
          CampaignID = campaigngroup.Key,
          DailyBudget = campaigngroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignBudget,
          Consumed = campaigngroup.Sum(q => q.Spent),
          RemainningCredit = campaigngroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignBudget - campaigngroup.Sum(q => q.Spent),
          Ads = campaigngroup.Select(ag => new {
              ID = ag.ID,
              Name = ag.Name,
              Spent = ag.Spent
          }).OrderBy(q => q.Spent)
      })
      .Where(q => q.Consumed <= q.DailyBudget).OrderByDescending(q => q.RemainningCredit).First();
```

Comment: Impressive query. Is there a reason you decided to start with Query syntax and end with Method syntax? I'm having trouble following what your query is doing. If you rewrite the query in Query syntax it might be easier to spot some optimizations

Comment: Could you post the generated SQL?

Comment: @Thom Smith, right from sql profiler https://gist.github.com/3872906, its 1500 line, but still runs in less than a second

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: It is helpful to provide feedback to answers. It gives an opportunity to work together to solve the problem and it makes the people who are answering questions feel like they haven't wasted their time.

Comment: @Aducci just the weekend :), i'm checking how the query performs now after the optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can simplify that query:

- `select into` lets you keep it all in query syntax.
- The `join ... into`/`from`/`DefaultIfMany` constructs implementing left joins can be replaced with `join ... into` construcs representing group joins.
- Some of the groups near the end cannot be empty, so `FirstOrDefault` is unnecessary.
- Some of the `where` conditions can be moved up to the top before the query gets complicated.

Here's the stab I took at it. The revisions were significant, so it might need a little debugging:

```
var rCampaign = ( 
    from a in db.AdCreative

    where a.AdDimensionID == AdSize &&
          a.AdGroup.Campaign.Starts <= rNow &&
          a.AdGroup.Campaign.Ends >= rNow &&
          a.AdGroup.AdHost.Select(q => q.ID).Contains(rPlatform.ID) &&
          a.AdGroup.AdPublisher.Select(q => q.ID).Contains(rPublisher.ID)

    join hit in db.AdHit.Where(h => h.HitType == 1 && h.LocationID == rLocationID)
        on a.ID equals hit.AdID
        into hits

    join loc in db.AdGroup_Location
        on a.AdGroupID equals loc.AdGroupID
        into locs

    where !locs.Any() || locs.Any(l => l.LocationID == rLocationID)

    select new {
        a.ID,
        a.Name,
        Spent = hits.Sum(h => h.AdDimension.Credit / 1000) ?? 0,
        CampaignID = a.AdGroup.Campaign.ID,
        CampaignName = a.AdGroup.Campaign.Name,
        CampaignBudget = a.AdGroup.Campaign.DailyBudget,
    } into adgroup
    group adgroup by adgroup.CampaignID into campaigngroup
    select new
    {
        CampaignID = campaigngroup.Key,
        DailyBudget = campaigngroup.First().CampaignBudget,
        Consumed = campaigngroup.Sum(q => q.Spent),
        RemainingCredit = campaigngroup.First().CampaignBudget - campaigngroup.Sum(q => q.Spent),
        Ads = campaigngroup.Select(ag => new {
            ag.ID,
            ag.Name,
            ag.Spent,
        }).OrderBy(q => q.Spent)
    } into q
    where q.Consumed <= q.DailyBudget
    orderby q.RemainingCredit desc)
    .First()
```

Comment: raw query from SQL Profiler is now 390 lines, takes less than a second to execute in asp.net, thanks all. But why were the old query executing in mssql in a fraction of a second and in asp.net in 50 seconds, where was the overhead?

Comment: My guess: having the two left joins interleaved ('join ... into'-'join ... into'-`from`-`from` rather than 'join ... into'-`from`-'join ... into'-`from`) confused it, and you weren't getting a simple left join.

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam I suspect your query improved because it refreshed the execution query plans. The join changes here do nothing to prevent execution query plan caching. On the backend, Linq is generating dynamic sql via stored procedures. Parameter sniffing takes control here and your fast query degrades every time you run it. In my case, integration tests start failing because of cached execution plans. You can write the linq 100 different ways but the underlying problem is not with the query, but with MS SQL database itself. The reason it improved is because the query plan refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored using Query syntax (Not sure if it improved readability). Removed one group by. Made some minor adjustments (replaced FirstOrDefault with Key property, changed Contains to Any). Hopefully it has some effect of speed.

```
 var rCampaign = (from cg in 
                   (from a in db.AdCreative
                    from subhits in db.AdHit.Where(h => a.ID == h.AdID)
                                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from subloc in db.AdGroup_Location.Where(l => a.AdGroupID == l.AdGroupID)
                                                      .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where a.AdGroup.AdHost.Any(q => q.ID == rPlatform.ID) &&
                          a.AdGroup.AdPublisher.Any(q => q.ID == rPublisher.ID) &&
                          a.AdDimensionID == AdSize &&
                          a.AdGroup.Campaign.Starts <= rNow &&
                          a.AdGroup.Campaign.Ends >= rNow &&
                          subhits.HitType == 1 &&
                          (subloc == null || subloc.LocationID == rLocationID)
                    group new { a, subhits } by new { ID = a.ID, a.Name, CampaignID = a.AdGroup.Campaign.ID, CampaignName = a.AdGroup.Campaign.Name, CampaignBudget = a.AdGroup.Campaign.DailyBudget } into g
                    select new 
                    {
                      ID = g.Key.ID,
                      Name = g.Key.Name,
                      Spent = g.Sum(x => (x.subhits.AdDimension != null) ? ((double)subhits.AdDimension.Credit / 1000) : 0),
                      CampaignID = g.Key.CampaignID,
                      CampaignName = g.Key.CampaignName,
                      CampaignBudget = g.Key.CampaignBudget                                    
                   })
                 group cg by new { cg.CampaignID, cg.CampaignBudget } into cg
                 let tempConsumed = cg.Sum(q => q.Spent)
                 let tempRemainningCredit = cg.Key.CampaignBudget - tempConsumed
                 where tempConsumed <= cg.Key.CampaignBudget
                 orderby tempRemainningCredit desc
                 select new
                 {
                   CampaignID = cg.Key.CampaignID,
                   DailyBudget = cg.Key.CampaignBudget,
                   Consumed = tempConsumed,
                   RemainningCredit = tempRemainningCredit,
                   Ads = from ag in cg
                         orderby ag.Spent
                         select new
                         {
                           ID = ag.ID,
                           Name = ag.Name,
                           Spent = ag.Spent
                          }
                  }).First();
```